# Common file called for every view load

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am new to MVC I need to know which method will get called for every view load in mvc. for example I need to verify the user is logged in or not in every view page load how can I write common method to verify user details on every view page load. I know there is a common file that runs on every view page hit. please guide me in this???

Answer (score 0):

> you can use _Partial view in your _Layout.cshtml and write some
>   business logic for that particular partial view

Answer (score 0):

May be what do you need is _Layout.cshtml, you can find in folder Views>Shared>

Comment: Will _Layout will hit on every page load even if I hardcore in browser will it hit??

Answer (score 0):

If you have worked in asp.net web forms,there is a page called **master page** which is common for all the html pages.

In mvc **Layout** pages are used for this purpose.you can find the layout page in views/shared directory in your project solution and modify it according to your need.

Just include that layout in your views where you want the layout by using

> layout ="path of the layout";

hope it will help.